# scala-sbt cannot use in Fedora

Tags: sbt

I need to use sbt for run spark in my fedora box, but what surprised me most is
sbt cannot use in my Fedora, I've tried two fedora machines, both failed.

I guess a lot of people meet this problem before, any ideas?

Thanks.

Jovi

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing? I have successfully used sbt on Fedora.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

For RPM based distributions ( http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html ) following instructions work:

```
curl https://bintray.com/sbt/rpm/rpm | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/bintray-sbt-rpm.repo
sudo yum install sbt
```

**OLD INSTRUCTIONS**

Setting up SBT on fedora is pretty straightforward.

Older version sbt-0.12.2:

```
$ sudo yum localinstall http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-native-packages/org/scala-sbt/sbt//0.12.2/sbt.rpm
```

Latest version sbt-0.13.1:

```
$ sudo yum localinstall http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-native-packages/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.1/sbt.rpm
```

Comment: This archive does not work anymore.  I am using: `sudo yum localinstall https://bintray.com/artifact/download/sbt/rpm/sbt-0.13.8.rpm
`

Comment: @BAR: updated instructions, check now.